# Root URL's for ServiceStack and .NET Core 2

Tags: c#, routes, servicestack, .net-core-2.0, .net-core-1.1

I've recently had cause to upgrade a servicestack service from .NET Core 1.1 to .NET Core 2.0.

Previously, my root URL was defined in the program class a bit like this...

`IWebHost host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseUrls("http://*:44444/api/myservice")
    .Build();
host.Run();`

With .NET Core 2.0, it appears that it is not possible to specify the root path in 'UseUrls' method - I get an exception which says `System.InvalidOperationException: A path base can only be configured using IApplicationBuilder.UsePathBase()` to use incorporate the [UsePathBaseMiddleware](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/pull/689/files) in order to set the root path.

I find, that when I specify just the root path + port number in the WebHostBuilder and set the UsePathBase in the apphost file (either before or after a call to `app.UseServiceStack(...)`) that everything is available from the root (i.e. I think my call to UsePathBase is being ignored?!).

My requests are decorated with a route attribute which look like this:

`[Route("users/{username}", "Get"]`

Using .NET Core 1.1, I was able to access this service at
`http://[URL]:[PORT]/api/user/users/[USERNAME]`

Using .NET Core 2.0, the service appears at
`http://[URL]:[PORT]/users/[USERNAME]`

Now, I can hard code the routes to include the '/api/user' prefix on each defined route attribute, or I think I can do something in GetRouteAttributes() in the AppHost to override all the discovered routes and apply a prefix as I need - but the metadata page always appears at the root address (i.e. `http://[URL]:[PORT]/metadata` ) rather than at `http://[URL]:[PORT]/api/[SERVICE]/metadata`.

This is a problem for me because I have dozens of services at the same public URL (the port is hidden by an API Gateway), so I need the metadata pages to appear at somewhere other than the root.

Is there an (preferably low-impact) way to make services routes behave as they did in .NET Core 1.1?

---

**UPDATE - 18/09/17 after a bit of research**

---

I've been able to find two ways of making this work (neither of them ideal...)

The first way:

This is a complete repo of my first solution. I figured out how to use `app.UsePathBase` to change to root URL, but the metadata detail pages don't take this path base into account, so they just show every service method starting from '/'

```
using Funq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using ServiceStack;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ServiceStackCore1Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "My Service";

            IWebHost host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls("http://*:32505/")
                .Build();
            host.Run();

        }
    }

    internal class PathSetupStartupFilter : IStartupFilter
    {
        public Action<IApplicationBuilder> Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> next)
        {
            return app =>
            {
                app.UsePathBase("/api/myservice");
                next(app);
            };
        }
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddLogging();
            services.AddTransient<IStartupFilter, PathSetupStartupFilter>();

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {

            loggerFactory.AddConsole((x, y) => y > LogLevel.Trace);
            app.UseServiceStack(Activator.CreateInstance<AppHost>());

            app.Run(context => Task.FromResult(0) as Task);
        }
    }

    public class AppHost : AppHostBase
    {
        public AppHost()
            : base("ASM Cloud - My Service", typeof(MyService).GetAssembly())
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Configure the given container with the
        /// registrations provided by the funqlet.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="container">Container to register.</param>
        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {
            this.Plugins.Add(new PostmanFeature());
        }
    }

    public class MyService : Service
    {
        public TestResponse Any(TestRequest request)
        {
            //throw new HttpError(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "SomeErrorCode");
            return new TestResponse { StatusCode = 218, UserName = request.UserName };
        }

        [Route("/test/{UserName}", "GET", Summary = "test")]
        public class TestRequest : IReturn<TestResponse>
        {

            public string UserName { get; set; }
        }

        public class TestResponse : IHasStatusCode
        {
            public int StatusCode { get; set; }
            public string UserName { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

The second way - this does provide correct functionality - both for service routing and metadata display **but Servicestack throws an exception when resolving the path at every call**. In this full repo, I use the HandlerFactoryPath to set my base URI, which according to servicestack docs should specify the base route of the application.

```
using Funq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using ServiceStack;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ServiceStackCore1Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "My Service";

            IWebHost host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls("http://*:32505/")
                .Build();
            host.Run();
        }
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddLogging();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole((x, y) => y > LogLevel.Trace);
            app.UseServiceStack(Activator.CreateInstance<AppHost>());

            app.Run(context => Task.FromResult(0) as Task);
        }
    }

    public class AppHost : AppHostBase
    {
        public AppHost()
            : base("My Service", typeof(MyService).GetAssembly())
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Configure the given container with the
        /// registrations provided by the funqlet.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="container">Container to register.</param>
        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {

            Plugins.Add(new PostmanFeature());
            SetConfig(new HostConfig
            {
                HandlerFactoryPath = "/api/myservice"
            });
        }
    }

    public class MyService : Service
    {
        public TestResponse Any(TestRequest request)
        {
            return new TestResponse { StatusCode = 200, UserName = request.UserName };
        }

        [Route("/test/{UserName}", "GET", Summary = "test")]
        public class TestRequest : IReturn<TestResponse>
        {
            public string UserName { get; set; }
        }

        public class TestResponse : IHasStatusCode
        {
            public int StatusCode { get; set; }
            public string UserName { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

So, like I said, this solution works, but throws an exception

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
>         Connection id "0HL7UFC5AIAO6", Request id "0HL7UFC5AIAO6:00000004": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
>   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
>   Parameter name: startIndex
>      at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
>      at ServiceStack.AppHostBase.d__7.MoveNext() in C:\BuildAgent\work\799c742886e82e6\src\ServiceStack\AppHostBase.NetCore.cs:line 101
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<ProcessRequestsAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
>   fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
>         Connection id "0HL7UFC5AIAO6", Request id "0HL7UFC5AIAO6:00000004": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
>   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
>   Parameter name: startIndex
>      at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
>      at ServiceStack.AppHostBase.<ProcessRequest>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\BuildAgent\work\799c742886e82e6\src\ServiceStack\AppHostBase.NetCore.cs:line 101
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame`1.d__2.MoveNext()

Findings aside, the actual problem (not the stuff I have shown above in the update) could be down to the following two issues with ASPNet hosting:

https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/815
https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/1120

I'm still at a bit of a loss as to what to do to solve my original problem - so I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you ever found a solution to this, but someone on the servicestack forums had the same issue (as did I myself when I started using CORE edition of servicestack).

if you have access to that forum, you can follow progress [here](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/net-core-2-0-and-custom-base-url-routing/4626)

and if you don't, in summary @mythz noted that:

"This is a breaking change they've added in .NET Core 2.0, we'll investigate to see if there's a workaround but otherwise I'd avoid fighting .NET Core conventions and just host it on a port and use a reverse proxy to implement the desired base hosting url."

Comment: Yeah, I knew about that because a colleague of mine posted that on the SS forum - thanks for adding the link to this post. It's not really an answer to the problem atm. I guess that if enough people are interested in this being sorted out then they will do something cunning to get round the problem. I can't mark this as the answer unfortunately - but have a +1 on me :)